# Put inherited class into object tag thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have problem with my thymeleaf code. I have three classes, abstract Product, child Vehicle and child Structure. It seems to me that thymeleaf only support class that is passed in controller method. In this case it is instance of Vehicle. Problem is what if I would like to use instance of class Structure, then I have to write th:object=${structure} instead of  th:object=${product}

Problem is solved temporarly with this:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${product}" method="post">
```

To

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${vehicle}" method="post">
```

Method in controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView editProduct(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("editProduct");
        
        Product product = new Vehicle(); //Product is abstract class, Vehicle is child class of Product
        product.setName("Name");
        product.setId(1L);
        product.setPrice(200);

        mav.addObject(product);
        return mav;
    }
```

Thymeleaf code

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${product}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <label for="id">Id:</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" id="id" name="id" readonly="readonly">
        </tr>
        <!-- I would use this for vehicle
        <tr>
            <label for="brand">Brand:</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{brand}"  id="brand" name="brand">
        </tr>
        -->
        <!-- I would use this for structure
        <tr>
            <label for="material">Material:</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{material}"  id="material" name="material">
        </tr>
        -->
        <tr>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"  id="name" name="name">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <label for="price">Price:</label>
            <input type="number" th:field="*{price}"  id="price" name=""price"">
        </tr>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Product class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Product {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private float price;
    
    public Product() {
        
    }
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Vehicle class

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle extends Product {

    @Column
    private String brand; 
    
    public Vehicle() {
        super();
    }
    
    public String getBrand() {
        return this.brand;
    }
    
    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }
}
```

@Entity
public class Structure extends Product {

```
@Column
private String material; 

public Structure() {
    super();
}

public String getMaterial() {
    return this.material;
}

public void setMaterial(String material) {
    this.material= material;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is this line:

`mav.addObject(product);`

This will add "product" to the model with the name "product" (since Product is the name of the class).

If you want to give the object in the model a specific name of your choosing, then use this method instead:

`mav.addObject("product", product);`

Now it won't matter what type the "product" object is. It will always be called "product" in the model.

See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods

> When a name is not explicitly specified, a default name is chosen based on the Object type, as explained in the javadoc for Conventions. You can always assign an explicit name by using the overloaded addAttribute method or through the name attribute on @ModelAttribute (for a return value).

Comment: Correct! I implemented by your example and it works. Thank you

Comment: @FallenCharge Please click "Accept" to accept the answer.  This will show everyone that the question has been answered, and it gives credit to the answer's author.  It's the best way to say "thanks" here.